# how to properly use numpy hstack

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I have a list of documents.
I use `TfidfVectorizer` to get the `dt_matrix`, that is a sparse matrix `<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>`

```
comments = get_comments()
tfidf_vector = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=tokenizer, lowercase=False)
dt_matrix = tfidf_vector.fit_transform(comments)
```

`dt_matrix` is something like this:

```
  (0, 642)  0.14738966496831196
  (0, 1577) 0.20377626427753473
  (0, 1166) 0.2947793299366239
  : :
 (1046, 166)    0.500700591796996
```

Now I would like to add to this matrix the length of the documents as feature.
So I have the `length` array. In the i-th position there is the length of the i-th document.

```
length=get_comments_length()
```

`length` is a numpy array, something like this:

```
[141  56  79 ...  26  26  26]
```

I try to do `hstack`:

```
features = np.hstack((dt_matrix, length))
```

I get this output:

```
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1048, 1047]
```

I printed the shapes:

```
print(np.shape(length))
print(np.shape(dt_matrix))
```

And the output is:

```
(1047,)
(1047, 2078)
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**:

`sparse.hstack((dt_matrix, length.reshape((length.shape[0], 1))))` this is the working code. Using `sparse` from `scipy`, thanks to @hpaulij and @kederrak for helping

Comment: What's the `type` of `dt_matrix`?  You mention sparse in passing but don't give any details.  If is one the `scipy.sparse` formats, you can't use `np.hstack` on it.  There is a `sparse.hstack`.

Comment: yea the type is `<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>`

Comment: @hpaulj tryied with sp.hstack and got the same: `ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1048, 1047]`

Comment: Where does that 1048 come from?  You claim one array is (1047) and the other (1047,2078).

Comment: I know, I'm surprised too. I printed the shapes and says as in the question: (1047,) for the array and (1047, 2078) for the matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [123]: from scipy import sparse
```

Make a scipy.sparse matrix:

```
In [124]: M = sparse.random(5,4,.2)                                                            
In [125]: M                                                                                    
Out[125]: 
<5x4 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 4 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [126]: print(M)                                                                             
  (0, 3)    0.006222105671732758
  (1, 0)    0.7198559134274957
  (2, 0)    0.3603986399431639
  (4, 2)    0.9519927602284366
In [127]: M.A                                                                                  
Out[127]: 
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.00622211],
       [0.71985591, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.36039864, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.95199276, 0.        ]])
In [128]: type(M)                                                                              
Out[128]: scipy.sparse.coo.coo_matrix
```

Trying to use a `hstack`:

```
In [129]: np.hstack([M, np.arange(5)[:,None]])                                                 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-129-f06fc972039d> in <module>
----> 1 np.hstack([M, np.arange(5)[:,None]])

<__array_function__ internals> in hstack(*args, **kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py in hstack(tup)
    341     # As a special case, dimension 0 of 1-dimensional arrays is "horizontal"
    342     if arrs and arrs[0].ndim == 1:
--> 343         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 0)
    344     else:
    345         return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, 
but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1
has 2 dimension(s)
```

Correct use of `sparse.hstack`:

```
In [130]: sparse.hstack([M, np.arange(5)[:,None]])                                             
Out[130]: 
<5x5 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 8 stored elements in COOrdinate format>
In [131]: _.A                                                                                  
Out[131]: 
array([[0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.00622211, 0.        ],
       [0.71985591, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 1.        ],
       [0.36039864, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 2.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 3.        ],
       [0.        , 0.        , 0.95199276, 0.        , 4.        ]])
```

If the 2nd array is shape (5,) instead of (5,1) I get your latest error:

```
In [132]: sparse.hstack([M, np.arange(5)])                                                     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-132-defd4158f59e> in <module>
----> 1 sparse.hstack([M, np.arange(5)])

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py in hstack(blocks, format, dtype)
    463 
    464     """
--> 465     return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
    466 
    467 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py in bmat(blocks, format, dtype)
    584                                                     exp=brow_lengths[i],
    585                                                     got=A.shape[0]))
--> 586                     raise ValueError(msg)
    587 
    588                 if bcol_lengths[j] == 0:

ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions. Got blocks[0,1].shape[0] == 1, expected 5.
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. running `sparse.hstack((dt_matrix, length))` i get this `ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions. Got blocks[0,1].shape[0] == 1, expected 1047.`

Comment: Your `length` is a list or 1d array, not the 2d array that I used.  Don't be sloppy!  Pay close attention to the dimensions.  If you want to add a column to a (n,m) matrix/array, you need to use a (n,1) array - that's true whether using `np.hstack` or `sparse`.

Comment: `sparse.hstack((dt_matrix, length.reshape((length.shape[0], 1))))` works, thanks :)

Comment: I'm new with this kind of tasks and i didn't knew that an array could have (n,) dimension and that (n,1) is different :( thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

you can use:

```
np.hstack((dt_matrix, length.reshape((1047, 1))))
```

or:

```
np.hstack((dt_matrix, length.reshape((length.shape[0], 1))))
```

from the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

> Parameters:    tup : sequence of ndarrays
>
> ```
> The arrays must have the same shape along all but the second axis
> ```

Comment: hi, thanks for answering, I didn't understood the answer at all but i triyed it and got this error for both lines: `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)` (edited after your edit)

Comment: @juuso you have to use reshape, they need to have the same number of rows, in your error it sais you have only 1 dimension for the first array, you have to reshape `length` array, `length.reshape((1047, 1))`

Comment: please help me to understand. I have an array with size of 1047 and a matrix with shape 1047, 2078 . I want to put the array as the last column of the matrix. They both actually have 1047 rows. I don't understand the warning, why length should have 2 dimensions?

Comment: that's the requirements if you want to use `np.hstack`, they need to have the same no of rows to be able to concatenate at per column

Comment: if you look in the documentation it says concatenation along the second axis, so you need to have a second dimension

Comment: @juuso did you use: `np.hstack((dt_matrix, length.reshape((length.shape[0], 1))))` ?

Comment: yea, I tryied both and got the same warning

Comment: how come? I just tried against np.ones with the same shape that you printed in your question

Comment: @juuso try again? I have switched the order of the arrays

Comment: I've already tryied with both orders... no changes. If some other info is required I can try to add something to make it clearer... i add a print of `dt_matrix` in the question text

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210508/discussion-between-juuso-and-kederrac).